# How to simulate two categorical variable data in R?

Tags: r

I have two categorical variables: AluFamily and AluOrientation. Alu Family has total 36 entries and contains three strings i.e. Alu J, Alu Y, Alu S. Alu orientation contains the following: Direct and Complementary. Alu orientation also has 36 entries.

I carried out a chi-squared test of independence and got a result suggesting that these two variables are associated with one another. Upon plotting few graphs, I found that Complementary Alu repeat is always found with Alu S whereas Direct Alu orientation is found with Alu J, Alu Y and Alu S

However, my data is not that large. It contains only 36 entries. I want to know is there a way I can simulate/generate data for these two variables and then find an association between them in R. I want to be certain that this association actually exists.

I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: You could simulate more data, but there's no magic. The simulation is based on the 36 cases and its validity is constrained by that. You can't learn something from the simulated data that you couldn't learn directly from the 36 cases and if the sample size is small enough that that it may lead to a false conclusion, such a false conclusion would propagate to the simulated data. If you could take a tiny sample of data and use simulation to have the same benefits of a large sample it would save companies and governments billions of dollars per year or more. Wouldn't that be nice? ;)

Comment: You can choose to simulate data that coroborates your finding or data that doesn't

Comment: You make a valid point. And that's what I thought too. But my teacher is adamant that I should simulate the data. But I thought exactly what you just said.

Comment: I agree with all the previous comments about simulation, but my question is, why are you needing to get more data if your statistical test already found a significant relationship?  Chi-square includes sample size in the computation, so what do you expect to gain here?  If you want information about stability, you could do some boot strapping on your data, but there is only so much you can do.

Comment: Reminds me of a story my old supervisor told me once about a grad student repeatedly copying and pasting rows from their small dataset to increase their sample size and reduce their p value. Genius!

Comment: Make sure you and your teacher are on the same page on what they are asking for.   Ask if they have a paper where they saw someone do this so you can understand the methods better (the nice way of saying, prove this is a real thing).  There may be a miscommunication, or if you are understanding them correctly, looking for an example and finding nothing may make them rethink their stance.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks @Barker and everyone else :)

Comment: Simulation might be useful if the question were what power your test has with the sample sizes you were using, but that will no bear directly on the observed "significance". If these results were logically embedded in other possible patterns, simulation might be useful to assess the potential that choosing any two such two features might yield a statistically significant result. You have not told us the scientific background so statistical advice you see above may be misguided.

Comment: Q is too vague to support coding effort. Need to close.